# Travis CI kick off build on new tag

Tags: deployment, github, travis-ci, github-pages

I am trying to use travis for continues integration with github. I want to create a custom deploy on new tags. The problem is I can not get travis to kick of the build when I create  tag.

I believe an alternative would be to create a release branch...

my travis.yml looks like this

```
language: node_js
node_js:
   - "0.10"
# whitelist
branches:
  only:
    - master

after_success:
  ./build/update-ghpages.sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few things:

Are you pushing your tags to github with `git push --tags`?
Are you pulling your tags on travis-ci with `git fetch --tags`?

You branch white list could also prevent tagged builds from running, as they could be blocked for not being master branch.

Are your tags based off branch `master`? If so then the last comment shouldn't apply, as the tagged commit should still be built from the commit on master and your deployment program will still recognize it is a tag if `git fetch --tags` is performed.

If none of these suggestions help you I'll be happy to take a look at your setup if you give me a link to your travis-ci build.

Comment: Yes I am pushing using `git push --tags`. I am not pulling on travis ci, how would you force it to pull on tags? that's what I am trying to achieve - meaning create a release/tag without code push. All my work is on master branch including the tags

Answer (score 1):

Safelisting also prevents tagged commits from being built. To allow tags trigger the build consider adding tags to the whitelist with regular expressions, for example /^v\d+.\d+(.\d+)?(-\S*)?$/ if you use v1.0 naming pattern
For additional information go [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Safelisting-or-blocklisting-branches)